# Can you give me a way to share my python's program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

I know that the title may not be very clear so here's my problem below: I'm pretty new to Python,

I've made a mini application in python for contact management (it's a simple program.py + a notepad where the information are stocked+some photos) , I've made an executable (.exe) to share it , I've made it with pyinstaller , the .exe work pretty well in my laptop but don't work otherwhere , the error messages are the following :

### 1- No error messanges generated.FormatMessageW;Parametre incorrect.

### then when i click Ok there is a second one

2- Error loading Python DLL 'c\users...._MEI50282\python37.dll
pyinstallerpython-3.xpython-2.7python

Comment: did u compiled it for both platform 32bit and 64bit?

Comment: how can i compiled it for both platforms ?

Comment: since its working on ur laptop, what is ur windows architecture?

Comment: 64bits , same in my brother's laptop where it doesn't work because he doesn't install python i geuss

Comment: check the other laptop, probably it is 32bit :-) in that case 64bit exe will not run in 32bit windows architecture, else there is missing dll or libraries. also after compiling the py to exe, the Target comp has nothing to do with python anymore. the solution is to compile ur py to 32bit coz it will work in both architecture 32 and 64. this could be done on visual studio and definitely avoid any bug.

Comment: the other laptop is 64bit

Comment: r u using both same windows version, i mean same win10? or win8.1?

Comment: no he's using win7 , me i use win10

Comment: that's it :-) you got the root cause, during compile you need to add win7 dependencies but actually win7 is deprecated, your only solution is to compile ur py into exe with visual studio community which is free version. download it from Microsoft source https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/free-developer-offers/

Comment: okay thank you i will try with visual studio but i have no idea how to do it with it

Comment: i updated my answer. upvote and check to close this thread.

Comment: so i forget about the visual studio ?

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is during compile you need to add win7 dependencies but actually win7 is deprecated, your only solution is to compile ur py into exe with py2exe and include both version 32 and 64 or 32 only coz it will run on both windows architectures. Follow this official tutorial from py2exe [py2exe](https://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Py2exeAndWin32ui)

upvote & check